# .NET Free Licensing Components

Tags: c#, winforms, components

I'm developing a WinForms application and i'm looking for free licencing component to protect her.

The scenario is simple (offline activation only) :

1. Customer install our product then he provide me a request code from my application.
2. We receive the request code and we send him a activate code.
3. The customer enter the activate code and he can use fully the application.

Thanks.

Comment: If it wasn't for the lack of research effort I'd be tempted to +1 this just for the "protect her"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main OSS licensing lib I've looked at is [Rhino Licensing](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-licensing). There is a good WPF sample included too to get you started as well as an admin tool to generate the keys.

I don't think it is currently being maintained though, so that may be an issue for you.